# How to drive a large Linear Actuator using the Grove - I2C motor driver and an ItsyBitsy RP2040?

Tags: i2c, adafruit-circuitpython, motordriver

Im looking for a way to control a linear actuator using the [Grove I2C Motor driver](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-I2C_Motor_Driver_V1.3/) and an ItsyBitsy RP2040. I have the right power supply (tried to hook up the linear actuator directly to the power supply, which worked), but now I would like to control the actuator using code (circuitPython). I tried looking for a library in the "adafruit-circuitpython-bundle-7" but couldn't find anything that seemed similar to the driver used in the Grove Arduino example. Do you know which library I can use to do this? I am looking for a simple example such as extend for 10s and retract for 10s.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it has a custom protocol over i2c. It might be worth searching for characteristic parts of the library on GitHub and similar to see if anyone has already created a MicroPython or CircuitPython library. This might be a partial implementation in Python: https://github.com/bokmann/GrovePi/tree/master/Software/Python/grove_i2c_motor_driver

Alternative is to write your own based on https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/Grove_I2C_Motor_Driver_v1_3 or use a different supported board.